# How do I use a static variable to keep track of highest age

Tags: java, variables, static

I currently have a Person class with the options of creating a name, age, email, and ssn, and validating their inputs. How would I use a static variable to keep track of the highest age entered for Person?

Comment: By writing code. Do you have a more specific question? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Every time you assign an age, you should check that age is not more than the highest age, if it is, that should be the highest age. (It's more difficult if you can decrease the age [not monotonic].)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your class have a method like

```
public void setAge(int age){
   this.age = age;
}
```

and you want get the highest age person.

Add a static attribute Person,
and in setAge method compare ages if the current person is higher than previous or previous is null, save the current

```
public class Person {

  private int age;

  // other attrs
  // ...

  public static Person highest;

  public void setAge(int age){
     this.age = age;
     if (highest == null || this.age > highest.getAge()){
        highest = this;
     }
  }

   // getters and setters

}
```

in this way you can get the highest age

```
int highestAge =   Person.highest.getAge();
```